# Transposed FIR filter: Alternative binary tree structure

Tags: finite-impulse-response

As part of an exercise, I have been assigned to find an alternative method of executing the additions of a transposed FIR filter. There is a hint stating that the alternative method should be in a form resembling a binary tree.
I figured that the leaves of the tree should be the product of x(n)*h(i), i=0,..,k but I am having trouble finding the actual solution.
What am I missing?

Edit:

After further research, [this paper was found](https://vbn.aau.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/241229094/Koch_DDECS16.pdf). It explains the tree-like structure of the adders of an FIR Filter.

Comment: That is indeed an odd exercise . An FIR filter is easy enough to transpose but the result doesn't look anything like a binary tree (to me). Do you have any constraint on the number of coefficients? Is it a power of 2?

Comment: @Hilmar The transposed FIR structure is given and the exercise requests to change only the part where additions and delays are made into a binary tree.  There is not any constrain on the number of coefficients, it is just referred as k.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at [this paper from Xilinx](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/application_notes/xapp219.pdf).

In particular, Figure 2 seems to do something like what you want:

[image: Xilinx Figure 2]

The cascaded adders on the right look like they'd eventually form a binary tree if you had a long enough filter.

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221627590_FIR_Filter_Synthesis_Algorithms_for_Minimizing_the_Delay_and_the_Number_of_Adders) has more of the transpose information, but the connection might not be as clear.

[image: Transpose version.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have seen this particular paper and fig2 is the structure of a non transposed fir filter. I am looking for the binary version of the transposed one.

Comment: @samiu In that case, you should expand upon your question and add references to what you've looked at that doesn't help. Please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/83755/edit) to add links to these references. Also, please add the "working" (thinking) that you've done to date.